# Is there a way to make Seurat not filter out gene of interest?

Tags: r, seurat

I am trying to determine the expression of certain genes in a cluster on Seurat but I think Seurat is filtering out the genes. Is there a way to tweak the parameters to get my gene of interest in the clusters provided? Thanks.

Here are my parameters

```
    #Jurkat 
Jurkat.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "C:/Users/cash/Desktop/scRNASeq analysis/Jurkat filtered_feature_bc_matrix/")
JLat.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "D:/scRNASeq PseudoGenome Analysis/JLatPseudo filtered_feature_bc_matrix/")
JLatInduced.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "D:/scRNASeq PseudoGenome Analysis/JLatInducedPseudo filtered_feature_bc_matrix/")
# Set up control object
ctrl <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = JLat.data, project = "JLAT_CTRL", min.cells = 5)
ctrl$stim <- "CTRL"
ctrl <- subset(ctrl, subset = nFeature_RNA > 300)
ctrl <- NormalizeData(ctrl, verbose = FALSE)
ctrl <- FindVariableFeatures(ctrl, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The FindVariableFeatures function does not filter genes, it simply selects the most variable genes in your dataset (irrespective of cluster), to inform the clustering and to normalise all the other genes. Even if your gene of interest doesnt come up in the Variable genes, that doesnt mean that it's going to get removed.

What happens when you run through the whole analysis down to the UMAP stage and plot a DimPlot or Vlnplot, can you see your gene of interest? I believe you should be able to....

Also, as a piece of advice, I would suggest normalising using the sctTransform method. See [here](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/sctransform_vignette.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. How can I then get this gene of interest in my cluster ? Yes, I changed my analysis to scTransform.

Comment: what do you mean get it in your cluster...? If your gene is not showing up then maybe it's not adequately expressed.... You could always look at the raw counts vs the normalised counts to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if this has solved your problem :) @DLI

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think what you are suggesting could be correct because I see the gene of interest in the raw counts and not the normalized counts. Can I run a cluster on raw counts?

Comment: You can, but that would not be informative in any way..... neither the proper way of doing an analysis as it ignores all the controls that are in place to attempt to accurately infer expression from RNAseq data... maybe your gene just isnt expressed as strongly as you thought it was, or there were experimental issues.

Comment: Yes that is true. Thanks so much for the help! Last question - is there a limit to the number of features that should be included in the test?